# How to Logout JID using agsXMPP library

Tags: c#, xmpp, agsxmpp

I am making a jabber application in c# using agsXMPP library.

i want to know how can i can log out the JID globally from all devices.

to Log out from same application the code i used works well and is as follows

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//logout
    {
        x.SocketDisconnect();//x is the xmpp client connection name
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

XmppClientConnection.Close();

and then wait for the OnClose event as notification.

Comment: but it do not make that JID disconnect from server from all devices.Like we see a feature in gmail.

Comment: That's how xmpp works. You can only logout you current resource. When Gmail logs out all resources then they have their own server extensions or remote control multiple resources